# What kind of AWS services should I use when deploying my React app?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I want to deploy my React App to AWS and looking for the best way for my use case. I want to be able to create a ci/cd pipeline so that multiple developers can deploy updates etc. At the same time I want to use AWS API Gateway when I do the CRUD-operations in my React application.

1. Is it possible to use AWS Codestar doing this and what Service should I use?
2. Is AWS Amplify an alternative for me considering my usecases?
3. When I tested Codestar and deployed a React App created with “npx create-react-app” it didn´t work when building although I changed necessary lines in buildspec.yml. But when I tried Codestar with a React Express App containing an express file kicking in every time I run script Start it worked. Can this be a problem deploying a React App with Codestar and can you w?
4. Am I forced to create a separate API gateway, dynamoDB and lambda functions and then external fetch data to my React App. I think it will be nicer to get the data "inside" AWS.

Comment: Your question may be better suited for the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing the react application js files inside the s3 bucket and use CloudFront CDN if you want CDN capability.

Comment: So your are saying that every developer in my team should build it locally before storing at s3? I thought the codestar or amplify would be a good usecase for a team/company working on an application.